# vuetify suddenly shows weird icons

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I have an admin page built with Vue, Vuetify, and Nuxt.
I have made no code changes but suddenly the icons dont show correctly to some of the users including myself.

Below is an example. Even the default icons dont show correctly

[image]

Below is vuetify related default generated code in `nuxt.config.js`

```
import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors';
buildModules: ['@nuxtjs/vuetify'],
vuetify: {
  customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss']
},
```

Comment: Got this too today! All my sites for the app using Vuetify both hosted on Google and on "localhost" dev environment. Is it something wrong with a Vuetify version?

Comment: Are those icons from the usual icon font? Maybe the icon font is not loaded, and a different font is used.

Comment: It's based on a problem with the CDN version of mdi icons. There are several issues already created on github: https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module/issues/298 or https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/10797

Answer (score 1):

It seems (for me at least) that it works ok on Firefox and Chrome while Safari and Firefox Developer Edition get strange icons, can this be verified?

Haven't tried IE or Edge.

---- EDITED ----
Nope, I restarted with "npm run serve" and then it works for a while and then it comes back. Damn that is a strange bug!!??